# Parsing JSON with Scala play framework - handling variable array elements?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I'm trying to parse a json string of search results of the following form:

```
"""
{
  "metadata": [
    "blah",
    "unimportant"
  ],
  "result": [
    {
      "type": "one",
      "title": "this",
      "weird": "attribute unique to this type",
      "other": 7
    },
    {
      "type": "two",
      "title": "that",
      "another_weird": "a different attribute unique to this second type",
      "another": "you get the idea"
    },
    {
      "type": "one",
      "title": "back to this type, which has the same fields as the other element of this type",
      "weird": "yep",
      "other": 8
    }
    ...
  ]
}
"""
```

There is a known, fixed number of `result` element types (given by the `type` field), each of which correspond to a unique schema. For a given search request, there can be any number of each type returned in any order (up to some fixed total).

Writing out the case classes and `Reads` implicits for each type is easy enough, but my question is around the best way to handle the variability in the `result` sequence... pattern matching seems the obvious choice, but I'm just not sure where or how with the play framework. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Per the suggestion in the comments, I gave it a go by attempting to read the `result` sequence as subtypes of a common base trait, but that didn't quite work. The following compiles, but doesn't parse the example json correctly. Any additional suggestions are welcome.

```
sealed trait Parent {def title: String}
case class One(`type`: String, title: String, weird: String, other: Int) extends Parent
case class Two(`type`: String, title: String, another_weird: String, another: String) extends Parent

case class SearchResponse(result: Seq[Parent], metadata: Seq[String])

implicit val oneReader = Json.reads[One]
implicit val twoReader = Json.reads[Two]
implicit val parentReader = Json.reads[Parent]

implicit val searchReader = (
  (__ \ "result").read[Seq[Parent]] and (__ \ "metadata").read[Seq[String]]
)(SearchResponse.apply _)

val searchResult = Json.fromJson[SearchResponse](json)
print(searchResult)
```

Comment: Did you try `sealed trait Parent { def title: String }` `case class One(title: String, weird: String, other: Int) extends Parent` `case class Two(title: String, another_weird: String, another: String) extends Parent` ?

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson

Comment: Yep, I did -- I guess my question is, given `result` is an arbitrary sequence of those cases, how should that be handled in the `Reads` implicit? Can I just read it as `Seq[Parent]`?

Comment: Yeah, `Seq[Parent]` sounds reasonable

Comment: Feel free to come back with your code if you have further questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define implicit `JsonConfiguration`

```
import play.api.libs.json._

sealed trait Parent {
  def title: String
}
case class One(title: String, weird: String, other: Int) extends Parent
case class Two(title: String, another_weird: String, another: String) extends Parent

case class SearchResponse(result: Seq[Parent], metadata: Seq[String])

implicit val cfg = JsonConfiguration(
  discriminator = "type",
  typeNaming = JsonNaming(_.toLowerCase)
)

implicit val oneReader    = Json.reads[One]
implicit val twoReader    = Json.reads[Two]
implicit val parentReader = Json.reads[Parent]
implicit val searchReader = Json.reads[SearchResponse]

val searchResult = Json.fromJson[SearchResponse](json)
println(searchResult)
// JsSuccess(SearchResponse(List(One(this,attribute unique to this type,7), Two(that,a different attribute unique to this second type,you get the idea), One(back to this type, which has the same fields as the other element of this type,yep,8)),List(blah, unimportant)),)
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated#Custom-Naming-Strategies

Comment: @abw Welcome. Just in case, if there were no such mechanism as `JsonConfiguration` in play-json we would just have to define a custom reader for `Parent`. For case classes (`One`, `Two`, `SearchResponse`) standard codecs would be ok.

Comment: Interesting... I may try that as well just for learning purposes, appreciate it!